# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.springbootApp.Accounts.Pojo.AccountsIO'

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting this issue in my AccountsServiceImpl, where I'm implementing the post mapping method which creates account. Can anyone help me to solve this, Thanks

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class AccountsEN {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "acc_no")
    private Long accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String customerAddress;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String customerPhone;

}

public interface AccountsRepo extends JpaRepository<AccountsIO,Long> {
}


@Service
public class AccountsServiceImpl implements AccountsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepo accountsRepo;

    @Override
    public String createAccount(AccountsIO accountsIO){
        AccountsEN accountsEN =new AccountsEN();
        accountsEN.setAccountNumber(accountsIO.getAccountNumber());
        accountsEN.setCustomerName(accountsIO.getCustomerName());
        accountsEN.setCustomerPhone(accountsIO.getCustomerPhone());
        accountsEN.setCustomerAddress(accountsIO.getCustomerAddress());
        accountsRepo.save(accountsEN);
        return "Successfully Created";
    }

}
```

It should save account details in database

Comment: Hello, it should be JpaRepository<AccountsEN,Long>